# created user account does not show in browser console

Tags: meteor

This Meteor app which uses accounts-password package and a custom login form with autopublish package removed, creates a user account using `Accounts.createUser` on the server.

Even though a user has been created and verified `db.users.find({}).pretty()` in the meteor mongo terminal, this command  `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` in the browser console gives an empty array `[]`

**edit**
`Meteor.user()` in the browser console returns `null`

**edit 2**
The steps to fire the Accouts.createUser is as follows:
A template button event calls a method A, which on the server it stores the username and password in a global object, then calls a method B which then calls a server side function which calls Acounts.createUser using the username and password in the global object.

server.js

```
Meteor.publish('users', function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId});
  }
});
```

client.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('users');
```

Is this normal? and if so, how does meteor know which browser "session" belongs to which client?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs for [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser):

> On the client, this function logs in as the newly created user on successful completion. On the server, it returns the newly created user id.

So if you only create the user from the server, the user won't be automatically logged in. If the user isn't logged in, his/her user document won't be published.

You have two choices:

1. Call `Accounts.createUser` from the client.
2. Ask the user to login after the account is created on the server.